# Push Notification in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating an Windows Phone 8.1 Application (not Silverlight Application). I want to implement Push Notificaion in my app but while I try to add Microsoft.Phone.dll to my application to use  HttpNotificationChannel, it shows exception on build as "Cannot find type System.SystemException in module mscorlib.dll".

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do that? Did you seen this sample? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/push-and-periodic-de225603/